# How do you get a one-time location to a specified accuracy?

Tags: iphone, navigation, gps, cllocationmanager

In the documentation it says that it gets an approximate location and then keeps updating with finer and finer precision.  I have a button that does

```
[locManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

and then I implement

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{
    [locManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

and have it get directions somwhere.  For some reason it's not updating locations when I drive somewhere.  I would assume this is because it gets the "general location", and then doesn't have enough time to get an accurate reading.  I also have

```
locManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
```

Any thoughts?  just need one time accurate readings.  stumped.  thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick hack solution:

```
if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy > 2*locManager.desiredAccuracy) {
  return;
}
```

A better solution might be to wait until accuracy stops improving, averaged over the last 5 updates or so.

Comment: so you're saying put a counter in the didUpdateLocation method and let it go 5 times before stopping?  Might work.  I'll try it.

Comment: No, you compare the five horizontalAccuracy values and wait until it stops getting better. Sticking a counter should work too, provided you have good GPS reception (you might not, and then what should it do?), but 5 might be too little.